# iOS9 - HTTP Connection Error

Tags: http, nsurlsession

I got 3 error when i update my Xcode

1- *App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.*

2- *CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)*

3- *NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)*

I tried:

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourdomain.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

and

```html
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

But they didn't work. Can anyone help me please! Thank You.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32912578/4588136 I just entered wrong place the code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Project Navigator click your project's name.
[image]

Now, on the right side you' ll see the General Tab of your project.Select the Info Tab
[image]
Expand the Customs iOS Target Properties
[image]
Add a new type, Name it as NSAppTransportSecurity, type as Dictionary.It will be convert in this text App Transport Security Settings
[image]
Inside that add a new item and name it as NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, type as Boolean, value YES.
[image]

See this thread on the forums for the further details what apple...
Add the entry to info.plist

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/5857#5857

And refer to Session 711 at WWDC.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=711

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day.

Comment: Note that Apple will likely reject apps that use the NSAllowsArbitratyLoads key when submitted to the app store - unless you have a really good reason. It is better to use NSExceptionDomains instead and list all of the domains you want to be exempt from the rule. Here is the link to the app transport security documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: Where is exactly apple say apps will be rejected for that exception? Every app that using one of the ad networks SDKs out there, is obligated to allow ArbitratyLoads. So I am really not sure what your'e saying is true.

Comment: @DocForNoc well its a security measure that your app will communicate with just those links that are white listed by you. if we allow all links for production phase too then our app would not be considered as safe and apple might not allow one's app with allow ArbitratyLoads.

Answer (score 3):

[add to the whitelist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TykQH.png)

[image]
Connect the wrong domain name was added to the whitelist, even if the domain name has been used for https.

Comment: please add image in the answer itself