# Xcode 7.3: NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)

Tags: ios, xcode

My project is running on Xcode 7.3.

When i just make a **GET** request i got the error as title and the information:

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

error message:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a >server that is pretending to be “https://api.domain.com” which >could put your confidential information at risk.

https://api.domain.com:9002

I search the solution but none works. Add these into **info.plist**

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
```

OR
(my current setting)

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>https://api.domain.com:9002</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

---

I Searched:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32912578/291240

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209583/291240

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34999957/291240

Comment: that happend only in GET method or all call of request.

Comment: Both GET and POST same error.

Comment: Refer [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23241872/nsurlconnection-cfurlconnection-http-load-failed-kcfstreamerrordomainssl-9813) it might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE SSL certificate used by your server is invalid, or your server is not https at all.

Please try connecting by using http:// instead of https://

PS: I am not able to open this link in my browser, https://api.domain.com:9002

but this could have been a placeholder, so please try this.

But otherwise, there is also a way, by which you can ignore the error:

WARNING - THIS WOULD ALSO make your code vulnerable to MitM attacks, So best this is to fix your SSL on server

Set your NSURLConnection delegate as self and add below code

```
    - (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    if ([trustedHosts containsObject:challenge.protectionSpace.host])
      [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

FOR NSURLSESSION check this answer, [NSURLSession Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20314162/4046561)

---

**UPDATE**

Above code will be vulnerable to MitM attacks,

please check this [SSL Pinning for NSURLSession](http://www.jonflanders.com/?p=1415), for a secured way.

Comment: thanks. It is https. But the ssl is invalid. I want escape them. But your method seems for NSURLConnection, which is good for IOS 6 and above, i want to use NSURLSession, any help on this?

Comment: thank you! It works! But another question is this only for development, does Apple will reject it if you submit this?

Comment: yes, they might. please check this for a secured method. http://www.jonflanders.com/?p=1415. Also updated my answer.